# Error with parameters not existing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, parameters

I am trying to get an insert/return primary key SQL query to run.

The query ends up looking like this:

```
declare @userid as integer;
insert into users (username,emailaddress,passwordhash,salt) values
 (@username,@email,@password,@salt);

set @userid=scope_identity();
insert into groups (name,userid) values ('somegroup',@userid);
select @userid;
```

This simply goes into the SqlCommand.CommandText field. So this is executed as a single query

I then add the parameters like this: (`cmd` is a `SqlCommand` object)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email",user.EmailAddress));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username",user.Username));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@salt",user.Salt));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", user.PasswordHash));
```

I then execute the query with `ExecuteScalar();` It will throw an error at this point though saying the parameter @email doesn't exist.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. If you send give null as the value of a parameter, it won't actually be added. So the solution(for me anyway, for you, it may involve `DBNull`) was to convert nulls into empty strings as so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email",user.EmailAddress ?? ""));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username",user.Username));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@salt",user.Salt ?? ""));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", user.PasswordHash ?? ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You must prefix all parameter names with an `@`, so this will work:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email",user.EmailAddress));
```

Comment: I've tried that and still doesn't work. The exact error is ""The parameterized query '(@email nvarchar(4000),@username nvarchar(5),@salt nvarchar(4000' expects the parameter '@email', which was not supplied."}"

Comment: can you update your question with you stored procedure call code?

Comment: this isn't a stored procedure. All of this is being executed as a query. ie, I do `cmd.CommandText="declare ..."`. It is being executed as a single query

Answer (score 0):

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
      //Your code should be here in this case, as you are not using SP. 
      //So this will help you in case of multiple users
)
```

Or

[Commit/Rollback Transaction](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gowth/3757/)